# convert a given table(rows) data to JSON with only the values of the column in java

Tags: json, algorithm, dictionary, java-8, jackson

I am new to java , Need some help on a approach to transform this table data :

```
Country State    City       County      short         urban
------------------------------------------------------------
USA     Georgia  Atlanta    Cherokee    north_side    true
USA     Georgia  Atlanta    Clayton     south_side    true
USA     Georgia  Macon      Crawford    beach_side    true
USA     Georgia  Macon      Bibb        bw_side       false
USA     Florida  Miami      Dade        nw_side       true
USA     Florida  Miami      Broward     mw_side       false
USA     Florida  Tampa      Hernando    crd_side      false
USA     Florida  Tampa      Pasco       sw_side       true
Mexico  Baja     Tijuana    Mexicali    pr_side       true
Mexico  Baja     Ciudad     Rotunda     fs_side       false
```

to the following json :

```
{
    "USA": {
        "Georgia": {
            "Atlanta": {
                "Cherokee": {
                    "short": "north_side",
                    "urban": "true"
                },
                "Clayton": {
                    "short": "south_side",
                    "urban": "true"
                }
            },
            "Macon": {
                "Crawford": {
                    "short": "beach_side",
                    "urban": "true"
                },
                "Bibb": {
                    "short": "bw_side",
                    "urban": "false"
                }
            }

        },
        "Florida": {
            "Miami": {
                "Dade": {
                    "short": "nw_side",
                    "urban": "true"
                },
                "Broward": {
                    "short": "mw_side",
                    "urban": "true"
                }
            },
            "Tampa": {
                "Hernando": {
                    "short": "crd_side",
                    "urban": "false"
                },
                "Pasco": {
                    "short": "sw_side",
                    "urban": "true"
                }
            }

        }
    },
    "Mexico": {
        "Baja": {
            "Tijuana": {
                "Mexicali": {
                    "short": "pr_side",
                    "urban": "true"
                }
            },
            "Ciudad": {
                "Rotunda": {
                    "short": "festival_side",
                    "urban": "false"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I did some research into the data structure to use but could not find anything useful, looks like I can use map but I can not use multimap from spring or apache. Any suggestion on what approach should I take ?

Comment: Which data structure is used to represent the table? Or is that part of what you don't know?

Comment: @BuildSlayer I am able to get the data from table, basically table is the structured in way to hold the data in those columns, creating a java object to store those values from table i.e.
`
Public Class TableData {
private String country;
private String state;
private String city;
private String county;
private String short;
private String urban OR private boolean isUrban;
`
//setter and getters of all these
I am looking for how to transform this data to json after I store the table data in list of java objects i.e.. TableData
}

Comment: `Public Class TableData
 {   
     private String country; 
     private String state; 
     private String city; 
     private String county; 
     private String short; 
     private String urban OR private boolean isUrban; 
}`